# Selecting specific items in a map

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

```
Terraform Version 0.14
```

I have a JSON file that has multiple objects. I get that file using the `local_file` data source.

```
data "local_file" "getJson" {
    filename = "${path.module}/sampleObject.json"
}
```

sampleObject.json:

```
{    
    "config":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "type":"typeA",
            "vm_name":"Linux1"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "type":"typeB",
            "vm_name":"Windows1"
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "type":"typeB",
            "vm_name":"Windows2"
         }
    ]
 }
```

I use a local variable to save and convert the contents of my JSON file to a usable Terraform objects with the `jsondecode` function. I believe the jsondecode function is converting my JSON object to a map ( I could be wrong). One of the attributes of my JSON object(s) is `type`. There are two possible values for `type` (`typeA` & `typeB`). I need a way to select all the objects in my JSON object that match a specific `type` (ie: type == "typeA"). The roadblock for me has been making sure the new collection is either a map or another collection that can be converted to a map using the `tomap()` function.

My sample code below does exactly what I need it to do using a for loop except... it saves it as a `Tuple`. In the For loop documentation, there is alternative to save it to an object using `{}` but I haven't been able to figure out how that works in my given example.

I've reached a point where I think I'm going about the problem wrong with using a for loop. I could use some advise on this. I also think If I can get the for loop to work using {} so the results are saved as an object, I should be able to convert that object to a map using the `tomap()` function without any issues.

I'm still new to Terraform and any guidance would be appreciated.

For loop [reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/for.html)

```
locals {    
    typeA = [ for x in jsondecode(data.local_file.getJson.content).config : x if x.type == "typeA" ]

    typeB = [for x in jsondecode(data.local_file.getJson.content).config : x if x.type == "typeB"]
}
```

This is a redacted sample of how I would use the results.

```
module "typeABuilder" {

  for_each = local.typeA

  vm_name = each.value.vm_name
  // Assign each attribute from the typeA objects
  // ...
  // ...
}

module "typeBBuilder" {
  
  for_each = local.typeB
  
  vm_name = each.value.vm_name
  // Assign each attribute from the typeB objects
  // ...
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show example of `sampleObject.json` and the code which uses it?

Comment: @Marcin I updated my post with a sample of my sample object